# Large numbers and Data Type

Tags: c#

If I wanted to add two natural numbers together that are more then 150 digits each what data type would I need to use?

Edit: using .Net 3.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4.0, the obvious solution is to use [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx), which is designed to handle arbitrary-size integers.

For .NET 3.5 or earlier, the [IntX](http://intx.codeplex.com/) library looks like a good option - seems to be well optimised. Or if you want something a bit lighter-weight/simpler, but still quite complete, [this BigInteger class posted on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/biginteger.aspx) looks decent.

Comment: Just to add, if you're using .Net 2.0, there's a codeproject here that may also be suitable: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/biginteger.aspx

Comment: And if youre on .NET < 4, you can probably find some BigInteger implementations out there. -- Here we go GTT got there first.

Comment: Yeah, you guys must have posted just as I was updating my reply. :) I've specified a couple of good options for <= .NET 3.5 now.

Answer (score 0):

3.5? Try using [IntX](http://intx.codeplex.com/). (Or if you're just adding, you can roll your own with arrays of bytes, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think any datatype can work on that much long numbers. You have to make use of logarithmic functions to do that.

Comment: Can you explain a little this a little more please